# Is there really no easy way to add an export statement (output to .csv) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, export

I have worked in SAS for much of my career and always found it easy to write a dataset out to csv using a proc export. I now am working in SQL Server and am not finding any similar functionality. Everything I find on the web refers to copy/paste the data into excel or using an export wizard. I don't like those options as the end goal is to automate this query and have the data output where it can be utilized by other programs. Is there any code based way to achieve this?

Comment: Any reason why these "other" programs can't access SQL Server directly and grab their data?

Comment: I would like to suggest SSIS-package and windows scheduled task

Comment: The other programs I'm referring to are in R and Python. I'm a novice in both and have successfully written queries over the server from both apps. The issue I run into is in the complexity of the queries. I have many subqueries embedded with joins. Also, I write out to temp tables to reuse the queries frequently. Both R and Python throw me syntax errors when running the sql code. I have tried adding the code directly and also have tried to just run the .sql file but have syntax errors in both cases.

Comment: Is there some reason the CSV file needs actually be created?  For example you just want to produce a report that users without direct database access can consume?  Or is the question really how to run a complex query in an SQL Server database from R or Python code?   Is the query static? could it be defined as view in the database that the R code just extracts from?

Comment: I kind of got off topic in my last comment but the overall purpose of my question is specific to the functionality of SQL. I'm using SSMS and it just seemed to me that all other tools (SAS, R, Python) have the ability to quickly and easily write out to CSV without using wizards or cutting and pasting so why doesn't SSMS? For the example I gave above, I am now rewriting the query in R but for future other purposes, I was hoping there was some way to simply write out a file from SSMS.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using SSMS? CTRL-T then execute your query, you'll get a text (csv) result. Alternatively, `Query` -> `Results to` -> `Results to Text`. Alternatively, you can right click the results grid and select `Save Results As`

For automation, you can use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job the writes the output of a query to a file.